# WSO2 parsing T24 response

Tags: wso2

I need to create custom mapping to parse the T24 transaction response.
The default mapping is working perfectly with the T24 inquiry response but not with the transaction response.

Examples for such inquiry are as follows:

```
*BI1427400008//1,TRANSACTION.TYPE=CD.NEW:1:1,DESCRIPTION=New Certificate ofDeposit:1:1,CUSTOMER.ID=1000304:1:1,DR.ACCOUNT=0220100030410500:1:1,DR.CCY=EGP:1:1,DR.AMOUNT=1500:1:1,VALUE.DATE=20141001:1:1,TXN.REFERENCE=LD1427400035:1:1,CR.CCY=EGP:1:1,CR.AMOUNT=1500:1:1,CD.TYPE=EGP10.500.6M.36M:1:1,MATURITY.DATE=20171001:1:1,PRIN.LIQ.ACCOUNT=0220100030410500:1:1,INTR.LIQ.ACCOUNT=0220100030410500:1:1,INTREST.RATE=12.0625:1:1,INTREST.AMOUNT=90.22:1:1,BRANCH=2:1:1,PROCESS.DATE=20141001:1:1,OFS.REQUEST.ID=ACCDI142740000832197.00:1:1,CURR.NO=1:1:1,INPUTTER=8_VERIPARK___OFS_TCS:1:1,DATE.TIME=1410300856:1:1,AUTHORISER=8_VERIPARK_OFS_TCS:1:1,CO.CODE=EG0010001:1:1,DEPT.CODE=17:1:1*
```

**I need help to parse the above response, or create a custom mapping, please support.**

Comment: please make it readable

Comment: What is not readable?
my issue is that I can't map the mentioned response in WSO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is comma separate string of OFS message, default Syntax of OFS Message is
APPLICATION,VERSION/COMMAND/SUBCOMMAND,USER/PASSWORD,ID,DATA

It should work with default parsing otherwise you can write your own parser in your preferred language.